# How much did Starfleet lose due to Narada?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

Are there canon estimates on how much (personnel, officers, ships) did Starfleet lose **due to Nero/Narada's actions**?

I'm interested in either absolute #s, or percentages of total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR - Anywhere between 5500-9000 Starfleet crew were lost because of the Narada

We know (from *Star Trek* 2009) only of three instances where Starfleet engaged the *Narada*:

1. Stardate 2233.04: [The Attack on the USS *Kelvin*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Attack_on_the_USS_Kelvin) - the *Narada* emerges from the black hole.  Casualties: ***USS Kelvin* +  'several' crew members** ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Attack_on_the_USS_Kelvin)), including Captain Robau.  We also know from Pike's speech that *800 people were saved*.  I estimate the casual rate at either a few (say, 10) or 100-200<sup>1</sup>.
2. Stardate 2258.42 : [The Destruction of Vulcan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Destruction_of_Vulcan) - between **7 to 9 ships were destroyed**, presumably with their entire crew complement.  If we assume they all had a similar crew complement to the *Kelvin*, this could be **5600 to 9000 people killed**.  Plus another two killed on the *Enterprise* (Olson and Puri).
3. Stardate 2258 : The Battle of Earth - **no casualties for Starfleet**, other than Spock's dignity

So, in total, that puts it at **8 to 10 ships and 5610 to 9000 casualties.**  Additionally, as pointed out by @Thomas, most of those ships had final-year cadets rushed onto the ships to deal with the emergency, so the majority of personnel killed were Starfleet's final-year cadets!

<sup>1</sup> **A note on the crew complement of the *USS Kelvin*:**

Ex Astris Scientia has developed two size estimates for the *Kelvin* - an 'official' and a more realistic estimate.  This influences my estimates above, so I'll detail it here:

**Officially**

According to this 'official' size-chart on [Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/fleet-chart-official-stxi.jpg), the *Kelvin* was approximately 642m long.  The most comparably sized ship I can find is the *Galaxy Class* which [Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/fleet-chart.jpg) claims is 642m long.  Now, the standard crew complement of a *Galaxy* class is 1,012 persons ([source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_class#Design_and_development)).  However, there are quite significant design differences in the two ships; the *Kelvin* appears to have a much thinner saucer section than the *Galaxy* Class.  Considering this, my best estimate of the crew complement of a *Kelvin* class would be approximately 900 - 1000.  You must appreciate that there is a slight size discrepancy, *and* that the *Galaxy Class* starship was about 100 years after the *Constitution* class in the non-reboot timeline.  It's reasonable to assume that in that time, many systems have become far more automated, requiring a smaller complement.  900-1000 seems a reasonable number considering a slightly smaller ship but likely requiring more maintenance.

**Realistically**

A more realistic estimate is based on the size of the *Newton* class which estimates the *Kelvin* to be 315m long ([source](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/size-annotations.htm)).  The closest ship I can find on [this sheet](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/fleet-chart.jpg) in terms of both time and size is the *Constitution* Refit.  [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class) indicates that the crew complement for that craft varied from 432-500.  Given that size is less than 800, and we know that at least 800 people were on the *Kelvin* initially because they were evacuated, as Pike says to Kirk in the bar, the best we can assume is that there were at least 800 people on board.

Comment: One thing to add there maybe is that  those 7-9 ships + enterprise contained all last year cadets the federation had (aside from those that were suspended). thus almost all of the last year cadets were killed during these happenings.

Comment: Were there any Starfleet losses in the Countdown comic book series?

Comment: @NikolaiDante Not as far as I'm aware of as it "just" tells the forestory. Thus in present time no.......in the future A LOT (whole federation and klingon fleets destroyed and even the future Enterprise at least badly damaged)

Comment: Two from the Enterprise? I know there was Crispy Fried Redshirt but who was the other one?

Comment: @Thomas sorry, I meant the Star Trek: Nero comic series set back in the past. Flicking through, I can only see Klingons going boom.

Comment: Ah I don't know that one sadly so no clue.    @IG_42 the other was the ships doctor (that is why bones became the doc)

Comment: @Thomas I vaguely recall that, was that one an offscreen death? Presumably another victim of asploded console, or maybe plasma conduit just to shake things up a little

Comment: @IG_42 yes when the narada struck the enterprise with the torpedo to the beam connecting secondary and main hull the medical bay got a direct hit. the only death mentioned (not shown on screen) was the doctor for that hit.

Comment: "Memory Alpha postulates that it has a crew complement of at least 800, so it seems most of the crew were probably saved." - is there a reason they offer to postulate that OTHER than "well if 800 were saved then at least 800 were on board" - in which case it may very well have been 2000 on board and minority saved

Comment: @DVK-in-exile I've done some further research and revised my estimate on the basis of the ship sizes.  Hope this improves the answer's quality!